# Is reverse proxy worth it if website requires login?

Tags: apache, nginx, reverse-proxy

Considering a website that requires user authentication, all pages  have a "welcome username" string that is different for each user (like most of the websites these days)

The application is caching different page components and sets correct last-modified headers also static content is served by a different machine using nginx.

I think a reverse proxy in this case will slow down the website, is this assumption wrong and I'm missing something here, could the reverse proxy still improve performance?

Answer (score 1):

You could serve your custom content ("Hello [user]") via json/javascript. In this manner, the load on the dynamic part of your server is simple - "What's my username?" rather then "Customise the homepage for user x".

Answer (score 0):

This has been covered in other threads, for example: https://serverfault.com/questions/87953/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-using-http-for-web-server-communication-with-app-se